# Selenium Junit Writing text from webelement into excel

Tags: selenium

I want to write the value from webpage into excel sheet. I tried with Getattribute value and get attribute text both are returning null. Here is the HTML code corresponding to the webelement:

```
   <span id="appointScheduleForm:preqno" class="commomSmallTextBox1">EXTAPPO-007</span>
```

I want to fetch the value EXTAPPO-007 to write it into excel . Please help

Comment: Place the code which you tried to retrieve the attribute value. It will help us to narrow down the cause.

Comment: Here is the code:                                         WebElement  MRN= AppLogin.f1.findElement(By.id("appointScheduleForm:preqno"));
  String mrn = MRN.getAttribute("text");              
         String mrn1 = MRN.getAttribute("value");